# Ethernet Connection Not Work (Xubuntu 15.04)

Tags: networking, xubuntu, 15.04, ethernet

I've been looking around and trying the answers in other places, but none of them have worked so far. I have an ethernet connection on an old laptop. I'm using Xubuntu 15.04. This ethernet connection will work at first. After awhile, it stops working. When I say stops working, specifically DHCP requests time out. The wireless adapter on this device works fine at all times. If I plug in a live boot USB the ethernet connection works fine in the live boot of Xubuntu 15.04 (or even 14 - don't remember what subversion that is now). If I reinstall Xubuntu from the live boot, then the ethernet connection will work fine for a time. Then it will start the same problem - DHCP requests time out. If I set a manual address, since the router is set to give it a static route anyways, then it will complete DHCP but not be able to ping out, either to the router or any other local device. It can always ping itself.

Anyone got any ideas? I want to say it might be some kind of failed update but there are no updates pending when I check on the wireless connection.

Comment: The wireless connection works? With the same "router"?

Comment: It does. I don't have any issues with the wireless. It may be a hardware issue, but I don't know, the fact that it works with the live boot makes me think it probably isn't.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently I fixed this myself. Tonight i changed my linux kernel for giggles and that fixed it. 3.19.0.21 breaks the DHCP requests, but they work again in 3.19.0.15. so that was the issue with my particular problem.